# jQuery  - How to get the value of the array stored in hidden field on button click ? 

Tags: php, jquery

How to retrieve the specific hidden field value on the click of the "showImages"

```
<span class="isymbol" id="showImages" href="Javascript:Void(0);"></span>

<input type="hidden" name="hdnplaceid[<?php echo $k; ?>]" id="hdnplaceid" value="<?php echo $PackageDetailsSightSeeing[$k]['deal_place_id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hdncityid[<?php echo $k; ?>]" id="hdncityid" value="<?php echo $PackageDetailsSightSeeing[$k]['deal_city_id']; ?>">
```

I tried this but everytime i get the same value irrespective of the button which i click

```
$('.isymbol').click( function() {
   var placeid= $("#hdnplaceid").val();

   //   $("#hdnplaceid").val();
   var cityid=$("#hdncityid").val();
   alert(placeid);
   alert(cityid);
   loadImagePopupBox();
});
```

The span and the input field are in a for loop. So they are dynamically generated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your original markup and specify by clicking on each  button which value should be retrieved?

Comment: By button i mean on click of the span

Comment: I know, you should have other span elements, right?

Comment: <span class="isymbol" id="showImages"> generates a button image. As it is in an array multiple span is in an array, multiple span are generated. How to get the specific hidden field value on particular span click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if span and hidden fields are in loop then try this:

php/html  code:

```
<span class="isymbol" id="showImages" href="Javascript:Void(0);" onclick="show_hidden_value(<?php echo $k; ?>)"></span>

<input type="hidden" name="hdnplaceid<?php echo $k; ?>" id="hdnplaceid" value="<?php echo $PackageDetailsSightSeeing[$k]['deal_place_id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hdncityid<?php echo $k; ?>" id="hdncityid" value="<?php echo $PackageDetailsSightSeeing[$k]['deal_city_id']; ?>">
```

javascript code:

```
function show_hidden_value(id){
  var placeid= $("#hdnplaceid"+id).val();


  var cityid=$("#hdncityid"+id).val();

  alert(placeid);
  alert(cityid);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```html
<span class="isymbol" id="[<?php echo $k; ?>]" href="Javascript:Void(0);"></span> 
<input type="hidden" name="hdnplaceid[<?php echo $k; ?>]" id="hdnplaceid" value="<?php echo $PackageDetailsSightSeeing[$k]['deal_place_id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hdncityid[<?php echo $k; ?>]" id="hdncityid" value="<?php echo $PackageDetailsSightSeeing[$k]['deal_city_id']; ?>">
```

jQuery:

```js
$('.isymbol').click( function() {
    var id = this.attr("id");
    var placeid= $("#hdnplaceid"+id).val();
    var cityid=$("#hdncityid"+id).val();
    alert(placeid);
    alert(cityid);  
});
```